# Ajax add to cart not updating cart content untill after refresh

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The ajax add to cart function of woocommerce doesn't seem to update the cart untill after I manually refresh the website.

This is the function for the cart widget I edited, and it seems to be working fine. It just doesn't refresh automatically.

```
class GeminiCart extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'gb_woocommerce_dropdown_cart',
            esc_html__('Gemini Bracelet Woocommerce Dropdown Cart', 'depot'),
            array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'Display a shop cart icon with a dropdown that shows products that are in the cart', 'depot' ), )
        );

        $this->setParams();
    }

    protected function setParams() {

        $this->params = array(
            array(
                'type'        => 'textfield',
                'name'        => 'woocommerce_dropdown_cart_margin',
                'title'       => esc_html__('Icon Margin', 'depot'),
                'description' => esc_html__('Insert margin in format: top right bottom left (e.g. 10px 5px 10px 5px)', 'depot')
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'dropdown',
                'name' => 'woocommerce_enable_cart_info',
                'title' => esc_html__('Enable Cart Info', 'depot'),
                'options' => depot_mikado_get_yes_no_select_array(false),
                'description' => esc_html__('Enabling this option will show cart info (products number and price) at the right side of dropdown cart icon', 'depot')
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Generate widget form based on $params attribute
     *
     * @param array $instance
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function form($instance) {
        if(is_array($this->params) && count($this->params)) {
            foreach($this->params as $param_array) {
                $param_name    = $param_array['name'];
                ${$param_name} = isset($instance[$param_name]) ? esc_attr($instance[$param_name]) : '';
            }

            foreach($this->params as $param) {
                switch($param['type']) {
                    case 'textfield':
                        ?>
                        <p>
                            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id($param['name'])); ?>"><?php echo
                                esc_html($param['title']); ?>:</label>
                            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id($param['name'])); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name($param['name'])); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(${$param['name']}); ?>"/>
                            <?php if(!empty($param['description'])) : ?>
                                <span class="mkd-field-description"><?php echo esc_html($param['description']); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </p>
                        <?php
                        break;
                    case 'dropdown':
                        ?>
                        <p>
                            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id($param['name'])); ?>"><?php echo
                                esc_html($param['title']); ?>:</label>
                            <?php if(isset($param['options']) && is_array($param['options']) && count($param['options'])) { ?>
                                <select class="widefat" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name($param['name'])); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id($param['name'])); ?>">
                                    <?php foreach($param['options'] as $param_option_key => $param_option_val) {
                                        $option_selected = '';
                                        if(${$param['name']} == $param_option_key) {
                                            $option_selected = 'selected';
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        <option <?php echo esc_attr($option_selected); ?> value="<?php echo esc_attr($param_option_key); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($param_option_val); ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if(!empty($param['description'])) : ?>
                                <span class="mkd-field-description"><?php echo esc_html($param['description']); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </p>

                        <?php
                        break;
                }
            }
        } else { ?>
            <p><?php esc_html_e('There are no options for this widget.', 'depot'); ?></p>
        <?php }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $new_instance
     * @param array $old_instance
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = array();
        foreach($this->params as $param) {
            $param_name = $param['name'];

            $instance[$param_name] = sanitize_text_field($new_instance[$param_name]);
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        global $woocommerce;

        $icon_styles = array();

        if ($instance['woocommerce_dropdown_cart_margin'] !== '') {
            $icon_styles[] = 'padding: ' . $instance['woocommerce_dropdown_cart_margin'];
        }

        $icon_class = 'mkd-cart-info-is-disabled';

        if (!empty($instance['woocommerce_enable_cart_info']) && $instance['woocommerce_enable_cart_info'] === 'yes') {
            $icon_class = 'mkd-cart-info-is-active';
        }

        $cart_description = depot_mikado_options()->getOptionValue('mkd_woo_dropdown_cart_description');
        ?>
        <div class="mkd-shopping-cart-holder <?php echo esc_html($icon_class); ?>" <?php depot_mikado_inline_style($icon_styles) ?>>
            <div class="mkd-shopping-cart-inner">
                <?php $cart_is_empty = sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) <= 0; ?>

                <a itemprop="url" class="mkd-header-cart" href="<?php echo esc_url($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url()); ?>">
                    <span class="mkd-cart-icon-text"><?php esc_html_e('CART', 'depot'); ?></span>
                    <span class="mkd-cart-info">
                    <span class="mkd-cart-info-total">( <?php echo wp_kses($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count()); ?> )</span>

                </span>
                </a>


                <?php if ( !$cart_is_empty ) : ?>
                    <div class="mkd-shopping-cart-dropdown">
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) :
                                $_product = $cart_item['data'];
                                // Only display if allowed
                                if ( ! $_product->exists() || $cart_item['quantity'] == 0 ) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                // Get price
                                if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '3.0' ) >= 0 ) {
                                    $product_price = get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' ) == 'excl' ? wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $_product ) : wc_get_price_including_tax( $_product );
                                } else {
                                    $product_price = get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' ) == 'excl' ? $_product->get_price_excluding_tax() : $_product->get_price_including_tax();
                                }
                                ?>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="mkd-item-image-holder">
                                        <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink( $cart_item['product_id'] )); ?>">
                                            <?php echo wp_kses($_product->get_image(), array(
                                                'img' => array(
                                                    'src' => true,
                                                    'width' => true,
                                                    'height' => true,
                                                    'class' => true,
                                                    'alt' => true,
                                                    'title' => true,
                                                    'id' => true
                                                )
                                            )); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mkd-item-info-holder">
                                        <h5 itemprop="name" class="mkd-product-title"><a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink( $cart_item['product_id'] )); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters('depot_mikado_woo_widget_cart_product_title', $_product->get_title(), $_product ); ?></a></h5>
                                        <span class="mkd-quantity"><?php echo esc_html($cart_item['quantity']); ?></span>
                                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'depot_mikado_woo_cart_item_price_html', wc_price( $product_price ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'depot_mikado_woo_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s"><span class="icon-arrows-remove"></span></a>', esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ), esc_html__('Remove this item', 'depot') ), $cart_item_key ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <div class="mkd-cart-bottom">
                                <div class="mkd-subtotal-holder clearfix">
                                    <span class="mkd-total"><?php esc_html_e( 'TOTAL:', 'depot' ); ?></span>
                                    <span class="mkd-total-amount">
                                    <?php echo wp_kses($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal(), array(
                                        'span' => array(
                                            'class' => true,
                                            'id' => true
                                        )
                                    )); ?>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                                <?php if(!empty($cart_description)) { ?>
                                    <div class="mkd-cart-description">
                                        <div class="mkd-cart-description-inner">
                                            <span><?php echo esc_html($cart_description); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <div class="mkd-btn-holder clearfix">
                                    <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo esc_url($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url()); ?>" class="mkd-view-cart" data-title="<?php esc_html_e('VIEW CART','depot'); ?>"><span><?php esc_html_e('VIEW CART','depot'); ?></span></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mkd-btn-holder clearfix">
                                    <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo esc_url($woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url()); ?>" class="mkd-view-cart" data-title="<?php esc_html_e('CHECKOUT','depot'); ?>"><span><?php esc_html_e('CHECKOUT','depot'); ?></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <div class="mkd-shopping-cart-dropdown">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="mkd-empty-cart"><?php esc_html_e( 'No products in the cart.', 'depot' ); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php


    }
}
```

I already implemented this function to make it update; but it doesn't change anything:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'iconic_cart_count_fragments', 10, 1 );

function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {

$fragments['mkd-header-cart'] = '<span class="mkd-cart-icon-text"><?php esc_html_e(\'CART\', \'depot\'); ?></span>
                    <span class="mkd-cart-info">
                    <span class="mkd-cart-info-total">( <?php echo wp_kses($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count()); ?> )</span>

                </span>';

return $fragments;

}
```

In wordpress itself I enabled the AJAX add to cart. 
The add to cart button also has the class add_to_cart_button

Answer (score 0):

The code that reloads those fragments can be found here: \plugins\woocommerce\assets\js\frontend\cart-fragments.js

To refresh WooCommerce widget you have to copy the code below

```
   var $fragment_refresh = {
        url: wc_cart_fragments_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace( '%%endpoint%%', 'get_refreshed_fragments' ),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function( data ) {
            if ( data && data.fragments ) {

                $.each( data.fragments, function( key, value ) {
                    $( key ).replaceWith( value );
                });

                if ( $supports_html5_storage ) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem( wc_cart_fragments_params.fragment_name, JSON.stringify( data.fragments ) );
                    set_cart_hash( data.cart_hash );

                    if ( data.cart_hash ) {
                        set_cart_creation_timestamp();
                    }
                }

                $( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_fragments_refreshed' );
            }
        }
    };
```

and to trigger the event you do this: `$.ajax( $fragment_refresh );`  OR `jQuery.ajax( $fragment_refresh );`

Comment: Do I just add that code to the js file? I made a child copy of it by copying the directory into my own child template, so i should add it to the js file in there right?

Comment: First just try this without above code.  $( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_reload_fragments' );